# Python elementree possible to get grand parent attribute value

Tags: python, elementtree

I have xml file with contents like below. From the XML wanted to extract value of name under user category if its attributes job matches values "al" and run matches value as "jps". Tried to extract the value using elementree but unable to. Not sure tried approach is correct.

```
   <maruti>
    <usrDirectory>/usr</usrDirectory>
    <shareDirectory>/share</shareDirectory>
    <jobLogDirectory>/logs</jobLogDirectory>
    <clients>
        <client>nexa-asia</client>
    </clients>

    <imax>
        <uri>imaxs://imax-asia.fb.bda.com:123</uri>
        <rootDn>o=lbr</rootDn>
        <pend>ou=nexa-asia,ou=clients,o=lbr</pend>
        <password>password</password>
    </imax>

    <enabling-aling-tags>
        <tag>alingDisabled</tag>
    </enabling-aling-tags>

    <maxh>999</maxh>

    <defaults>
        <default type="slone">
            <user>pot</user>
            <exec>/usr/local/smarts/utils/runals.sh</exec>
            <env>
                <var name="ALARM">/taj/63123.lbr/ALARM</var>
                <var name="TODAY">/taj/63123.lbr/TODAY</var>
                <var name="jps_HOME">/usr/juju</var>
            </env>
        </default>
        <default type="slanamb">
            <user>pot</user>
            <exec>/usr/local/smarts/utils/runals.sh</exec>
            <env>
                <var name="ALARM">/taj/63123.lbr/ALARM</var>
                <var name="TODAY">/taj/63123.lbr/TODAY</var>
                <var name="jps_HOME">/usr/juju</var>
            </env>
        </default>
        <default type="slaljps">
            <user>pot</user>
            <exec>/use-ALARM/runmrts.sh</exec>
            <env>
                <var name="jps_HOME">/usr/juju</var>
            </env>
        </default>
        <default type="slanjps">
            <user>pot</user>
            <exec>/use-ALARM/runmrts.sh</exec>
            <env>
                <var name="jps_HOME">/usr/juju</var>
            </env>
        </default>
        <default type="cmj">
            <user>pot</user>
            <exec>/use-ALARM/runmrts.sh</exec>
            <env>
                <var name="jps_HOME">/usr/juju</var>
            </env>
        </default>
        <default type="cbj">
            <user>pot</user>
            <exec>/use-ALARM/runmrts.sh</exec>
            <env>
                <var name="jps_HOME">/usr/juju</var>
            </env>
        </default>
        <default type="slm">
            <user>favactor</user>
            <exec>/usr/local/actdrive/actdrive</exec>
            <args>
                <arg name="config">/usr01/lbr/conf/lbr-naming.properties</arg>
            </args>
        </default>
        <default type="tata">
            <user>pot</user>
            <exec>/use-ALARM/tataals.sh</exec>
            <env>
                <var name="jps_HOME">/usr/juju</var>
            </env>
        </default>
    </defaults>

    <groups>
        <user name="nexa_sit" annvday="20221003" make="one">
            <jobs>
                <job kind="al" run="jps">
                    <args>
                        <arg name="level">5000</arg>
                    </args>
                </job>
                <job kind="vm" run="jps">
                    <args>
                        <arg name="level">5000</arg>
                    </args>
                </job>
            </jobs>
        </user>


        <user name="nexa_tsx" annvday="20230714" make="two">
            <jobs>
                <job kind="al" run="jps">
                    <args>
                        <arg name="level">5000</arg>
                    </args>
                </job>
                <job kind="vm" run="jps">
                    <args>
                        <arg name="level">5000</arg>
                    </args>
                </job>
            </jobs>
        </user>


        <user name="nexatwo_bvk" annvday="20221003" make="one">
            <jobs>
                <job kind="al" run="jps">
                    <args>
                        <arg name="level">5000</arg>
                    </args>
                </job>
                <job kind="vm" run="jps">
                    <args>
                        <arg name="level">5000</arg>
                    </args>
                </job>
            </jobs>
        </user>

        <user name="nexaone_bvk" annvday="20221003" make="one">
            <jobs>
                <job kind="al" run="ips">
                    <args>
                        <arg name="level">5000</arg>
                    </args>
                </job>
                <job kind="vm" run="ips">
                    <args>
                        <arg name="level">5000</arg>
                    </args>
                </job>
            </jobs>
        </user>

       </groups>
   </maruti>
```

But later from error realised getparent is not supported. unsure how to extract.

**Tried code**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('text.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for sub in root.findall(".//user/jobs/job"):
 if (sub.attrib["run"] == 'java' and sub.attrib["kind"] == 'al'):
  print sub.getparent()
```

**Expected output**

```
nexa_set
nexa_tfex
nexatwo_set
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, since this is the `xml` package from Python's standard library, you get a fairly limited interface, and have no access to handy navigation features such as a `.getparent()` method.

One option is to use `lxml` instead of `xml`, which, though not included in the standard library, does have more advanced features, including a way to navigate the node tree in an object-oriented fashion.

However, using `xml`, you still have the power of XPath itself, or at least [a limited subset thereof](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support), which does allow you to perform what you need.

From the selected `job` node, you can return to its grandparent (`user`) once you verified that the given `job` has the desired attribute values, by using the `..` axis (sort-of like an operator that describes a tree node relationship) as many times as you want to step upwards in the hierarchy.

However, since you are performing navigation within XPath *after* verifying the grandchild, it is implied that you need to perform the verification in XPath as well. XPath provides predicates for this, expressions enclosed in square brackets `[` `]`:

```py
".//user/jobs/job[@run='jps'][@kind='al']"
```

The above expression means "all `job` nodes whose parent is a `jobs` node whose parent is a `user` node that can be located anywhere in the document, with said `job` nodes having an attribute named `run` with value equal to the string `jps`, and an attribute `kind` with string value `al`.

From this point, you can use the parent axis shorthand twice to get back to the grandparent, `user`:

```py
".//user/jobs/job[@run='jps'][@kind='al']/../.."
```

Since you performed all the necessary steps in your XPath query, you won't even need to bother writing an `if` statement when you step back into Python's world.

EDIT: Note that compared to your `if`-testing approach, if a `user/jobs/job` object were found that did have either a `run` or a `kind` attribute, or had both attributes, but with different than expected values, the XPath method would simply silently ignore them, while your dict member access operator would throw an error (probably `KeyError`).